# ASP.NET MVC app can't find Views since I moved my app to a new directory

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I copied my app and put it somewhere else. Then I changed IIS to look at the new place and ran it. Debugging it - it runs through my Controllers in the new location fine. But when it nips off to get the view it goes to the old location of my app?!?

Comment: which view engine you are using?

Comment: stop the old web site and see what happens.

Comment: i did. well better than that it isn't even a website anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used .NET Reflector to work out how the route engine works. Turns out it kind of caches the route. It wouldn't listen to me until I restarted IIS, renamed the old directory so it didn't exist anymore and stopped my devenv.exe process. **Then** finally it was sorted

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed anything in your Routes? The Routing engine is what grabs your views when the controller requests them. Perhaps your issue is in your global.asax file? I'm afraid that's all I can offer, without more information.